# Arrow symbol which is used to define a function. vertical line is attached to a tail (endpoint where no tip) of an arrow

Tags: arrows

I found the following arrow notation in the [Type Theory and Formal Proof: An Introduction](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Rob-Nederpelt/dp/110703650X)

[image]

How can I depict(draw) it using Tex?

I've browsed to find it but failed to.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\mapsto` in math mode.

I knew now that this symbol is used in mapping.